Union of conjugacy classes of non-conjugate subgroups
Let $G$ be a finite group and $H,H'$ non-conjugate subgroups. Then is it true that
$$\bigcup_{g\in G} gHg^{-1} \neq \bigcup_{g\in G} gH'g^{-1}.$$
In the case one contains the other this is a simple counting arguement[This was wrong, see comments]. But I havent been able to go any further than that.

I am curious what the simple counting argument is which reduces to the case $H\cap H'=1$, given that Haran's answer satisfies $H<H'$. (Also, note that $H\not<H'$ does not imply $H\cap H'=1$.

@coiso Yes you are correct, it seems I made a mistake. My thought was if $H=G$, then this is a well known thing. And I convinced myself this would extend this to $H<H'$ which clearly was not the case.

Also I have no idea how I got the $H\cap H'$ condition. I am looking over my notes and I wrote something about action on $G/(H\cap H')$?? Seems like complete nonsense oops.

Consider the finite group $G = \mathbb{F}_2^2 \rtimes GL(\mathbb{F}_2^2)$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(1, 0)$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ and let $H'$ be the subgroup $\mathbb{F}_2^2$. One can verify that both unions are equal to $H'$.

How did you find this?

The idea was to get an example with $H \lneq H'$. Furthermore, it's natural to try to construct a counterexample using semidirect products since it allows you to use outer automorphisms of groups with large automorphism groups.

Thanks! I was hoping the statement was true for my research but I guess it makes sense. Nice example!

This group is better known as $S_4$. Its subgroup $A_4$ also works as a counterexample.
